# if cell contains then

Tags: excel, vba

This is very simple question and I don't know where the problem is.

I want VBA to go through all the rows in the sheet and perform an action for X row if the cell in X row, Y column contains value different then "All OK" (or in other way - if specific cell contains "Action Needed"). It has to be with a loop (no issues with the loop).

One important information is that "All OK" or "Action Needed" are not values as such - are triggered by a formula "=IF(OR(B2<>"",C2<>"",D2<>""),"Action Needed","All OK")".

Also something that I noticed is that when I run the macro with a toggle breakpoint slowly, it works properly. However, if I run this with a run button without any breaking points, it is throwing all the lines (regardless if "All OK" or "Action Needed"). Any idea why?

```
Sub SplitToWorksheets()
Dim ColHead As String
Dim ColHeadCell As Range
Dim iCol As Integer
Dim iRow As Long 'row index on Fan Data sheet
Dim Lrow As Integer 'row index on individual destination sheet
Dim Dsheet As Worksheet 'destination worksheet
Dim fsheet As Worksheet 'fan data worksheet (assumed active)
Dim status As String
Dim ws As Worksheet

OptimizeVBA True

Set fsheet = Worksheets("CM | Impact")

iCol = 1
status = "Action Needed"

i = fsheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

For iRow = 2 To i

If fsheet.Cells(iRow, 5) = status Then

If Not SheetExists(CStr(fsheet.Cells(iRow, iCol).Value)) Then
Set Dsheet = Worksheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
Dsheet.Name = CStr(fsheet.Cells(iRow, iCol).Value)
fsheet.Rows(1).Copy Destination:=Dsheet.Rows(1)

Else
Set Dsheet = Worksheets(CStr(fsheet.Cells(iRow, iCol).Value))
End If

Lrow = Dsheet.Cells(10000, iCol).End(xlUp).Row
fsheet.Rows(iRow).Copy Destination:=Dsheet.Rows(Lrow + 1)

Else 
End If

Next iRow
```

thanks a lot for help!

EDIT: It works well when I pasted formulas (the one that triggers "All OK" or "Action Needed" as values, but i want to keep formulas when running the code...

Comment: so if i follow this correctly, basically all you want your code to do is loop through the first column of CM|IMpact and column 5 = action needed move that row to a new sheet?

Comment: Hi Doug! Thank you for the comment. Yes, do the loop through ALL rows and if column 5 <> "All OK" I want to make an action (copy row to the new tab).

Note that "All OK" in column 5 is triggered by IF formula, there is no "value".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got to jet to a family thing but between a few house chores and this I wrote you some nifty code.

The issue to solve youre problem with the formulas - you need to force the cell to calculate before pickup up the value.

```
 .Calculate
```

However, looping through worksheets is for the most part bad practice. Learn to do things in arrays. For some reason its including a blank row, but dont have time to figure it out, however this is something i suggest you learn, understand and commit to memory.

```
Private Sub MarekResCodeChange()
    Dim pickUp As Variant, vArr As Variant
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, z As Long, y As Long
    Dim dropOff() As String, sheetname As String
    y = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CM | Impact").UsedRange.Columns.Count
    j = 1
    ReDim dropOff(1 To y, 1)
    pickUp = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CM | Impact").UsedRange
    For i = LBound(pickUp, 1) To UBound(pickUp, 1)
        If pickUp(i, 5) = "Action Needed" Then
            For z = 1 To y
                Debug.Print ; pickUp(i, z)
                dropOff(z, j) = pickUp(i, z)
            Next z
            j = j + 1
            ReDim Preserve dropOff(1 To y, j)
        End If
    Next i
    vArr = Split(Cells(1, y).Address(True, False), "$")
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
    Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count).Range("a1:" & vArr(0) & j).Value = Application.Transpose(dropOff)
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow, that's powerful! Works amazing! Just some questions/notes.

1. Where can I learn more about arrays, do you have a good source? 

2. First column in my sheet is storing name of the country/region. These ones are repeatable across whole dataset. What I would like to do so is following:
* Create the new sheet for each unique name in column A (in sheet "CM | Impact")
* When looping through the main sheet ("CM | Impact"), copy row and paste into new relevant sheet.

Example: If first row in main sheet, column A is showing "Nordics", then copy row and paste into sheet "Nordics", etc.

Comment: Well first off for arrays, its a pretty basic tool in the tool box - any vba tutorial will teach you everything you need to know. There is going to be a small learning curve getting used ot working with them - but it'll be worth the small amount of effort itll take to do so. I think of arrays pretty much like excel work books. single dimension array is a column, a 2 dimensional array is rows and columns and a three dimension array is sheets pof rows and columns, your other question,  easy  - just add a sheet, name the workbooks.count the desired name and dump array piece to sheet